# Creating python virtualenv is failing

Tags: python, virtualenv

Creating `python3.10` `virtualenv` is failing

```py
$python -v -m virtualenv   --python /usr/bin/python3.10 py310

# /home/test/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/virtualenv/activation/python/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc matches /home/test/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/virtualenv/activation/python/__init__.py
# code object from '/home/test/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/virtualenv/activation/python/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc'
import 'virtualenv.activation.python' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fc0a0849810>
# /home/test/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/virtualenv/activation/xonsh/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc matches /home/test/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/virtualenv/activation/xonsh/__init__.py
# code object from '/home/test/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/virtualenv/activation/xonsh/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc'
import 'virtualenv.activation.xonsh' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fc0a0849d90>
import 'virtualenv.activation' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fc0a0aa3c90>
KeyError: 'scripts'
```

Comment: Could you please provide tox.ini and the output of `tox -rvv`?

Comment: @Jurgen Thanks for your response. Updated the Questions with above details

Comment: Is there a `scripts` somewhere? Maybe in a `setup.py`, a `setup.cfg`, or `pyproject.toml`? If yes, I recommend you copy paste the content of this file (at least the relevant parts if not the full file).

Comment: no @Sinoroc. I did not find  scripts in any of the files. Update the Question It looks the error is due to creating virtualenv. even just running virtualenv seeing this issue

Comment: Then I recommend you rewrite your question by focusing on *virtualenv*, and I would probably remove references to *tox* if I were you. -- Can you recreate the issue with `/usr/bin/python3.10 -m venv py310`?

Comment: Do you have a `VIRTUALENV_SCRIPTS` environment variable? Or maybe a `scripts` key in a *virtualenv* configuration file somewhere? Maybe at `~/.config/virtualenv/virtualenv.ini`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue. You need to locate which virtualenv it is using and upgrade it to latest version (at the time of this writing, the latest version is 20.23.0)

Answer (score 0):

Python was pointing to old version (python3.7). So basiclly i was trying to create python3.10 env using old version (python3.7) which is invalid.

Two ways to fix this

- Point `Python` or `python3` to the latest version (python3.10)
- or create env using the same or higher version

```bash
$python3.10 -v -m virtualenv   --python /usr/bin/python3.10 py310
```